# How to show / Hide based on isSelected property and another list item property?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a list of lvAccessPoints which has 3 properties, 
1)name
2)password
3)isSecured

i a texbox and button in each item, which i am currently showing when an item is selected.

so now when i select one item text box and button will come up.

But i also want to check the property isSecured for showing textbox

condition is

```
       textbox=> visible: if item is selected and has isSecured property true
       hidden:if isSecured is false (irrespective of selected or not)




<ListView Margin="0" Name="lvAccessPoints" Background="#ff1d1d1d" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!--<iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="ConnectionWifi" Foreground="White" Width="30" Height="30"/>-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Points.Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Padding="10,0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     x:Name="txt"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Text="{Binding Password}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="200"
                     Height="28"
                     Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed"  Width="100" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF2d89ef" Foreground="White" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click_1">
                                <TextBlock Text="Connect" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </WrapPanel>


                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

To show the text box i need to check 2 properties one is isSecured, and another is isSelectd.

How can i change my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `MultiDataTrigger`:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=points.isSecured}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: its not working, isSecured is the property in the list item., that is causing problem